# Flip content of a div on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning this 3D effect of flipping content of a div. On hover the div code below works perfectly. But What I want is that, if someone only click on the button flip this flipping of div should work. I want this flipping effect only if button is clicked not if hover or anything.

```
    <style>
    #f1_container {
      position: relative;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 450px;
      height: 281px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #f1_container {
      perspective: 1000;
    }
    #f1_card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: all 1.0s linear;
    }
    #f1_container:hover #f1_card {
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
      box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
    }
    .face {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .face.back {
      display: block;
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="f1_container">
    <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
      <div class="front face">
    lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />
    lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />
    lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
        <p>Any content can go here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="flip_content">Flip</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to handle click events on `button`.

#### 1<sup>st</sup> Approach: Using `.classList.toggle()`.

`content.classList.toggle('flip')` will add the class `.flip`, if it doesn't exist and will remove if it exists.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('flip_content');
var content = document.getElementById('f1_card');
btn.onclick = function() {
  content.classList.toggle('flip');
}
```

```css
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="f1_container">
  <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
    <div class="front face">
      lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
      <p>Any content can go here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="flip_content">Flip</button>
```

---

#### 2<sup>nd</sup> Approach: Using `.classList.add()` and `.classList.remove()`.

You could keep track of clicks, if the count is divisible by `2`, add the class `.flip`, else remove it.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('flip_content');
var content = document.getElementById('f1_card');
var c = 0;
btn.onclick = function() {
  (c++ % 2 == 0) ? content.classList.add('flip'): content.classList.remove('flip');
}
```

```css
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="f1_container">
  <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
    <div class="front face">lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
      <p>Any content can go here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="flip_content">Flip</button>
```

---

#### 3<sup>rd</sup> Approach: Using `.className`.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('flip_content');
var content = document.getElementById('f1_card');
var c = 0;
btn.onclick = function() {
  content.className = (c++ % 2 == 0) ? content.className + ' flip' : content.className.split(' ')[0];
}
```

```css
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="f1_container">
  <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
    <div class="front face">lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />lets see if anything happen
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
      <p>Any content can go here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="flip_content">Flip</button>
```

---

`.classList` returns an array of all `class`es assigned to the element.

For instance,

```
<div id="div" class="one two three four five"></div>

document.getElementById('div').classList
//['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

---

`.className` returns a string of all `class`es(comma seperated) assigned to the element.

For instance,

```
<div id="div" class="one two three four five"></div>

document.getElementById('div').className
//'one two three four five'
```

---

Comment: hey! this do not work in IE or Chrome. How can I make this work in those browsers?

Comment: @asdlfkjlkj - Alternatively you could use `.add()` and `.remove()`. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/hvrun9ww/).

Comment: @asdlfkjlkj - Or you could use [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/hvrun9ww/4/).

Comment: @asdlfkjlkj - You could simplify the first example to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/hvrun9ww/5/) and the second one to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/hvrun9ww/6/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add js, here shown with jquery to trigger a class change instead of hover

```
$(function(){
    $('#flip_content').click(function(e){
        $('#f1_container').addClass('flip');
    });
});
```

And change the hover selector to the class .flip

```
#f1_container.flip #f1_card {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some JavaScript for this like so:

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cjLm77ek/

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#flip_content").click(function() {

        $("#f1_card").css("transform", "rotateX(180deg)");
        $("#f1_card").css("box-shadow", "-5px 5px 5px #aaa");

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="f1_container">
    <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
        <div class="front face">lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />lets see if anything happen
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
            <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
            <p>Any content can go here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="flip_content">Flip</button>
```

CSS:

```
#f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}

/* disable hover change
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
*/

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using only CSS by using the checkbox:

Also you can give more custom styling to the label to make it look like a button and place it anywhere in the HTML but note the checkbox that i added in in the `f1_container`. It should be right before the element you want to flip.

This solution does has limitation that it works fine only on modern browsers.

JSFiddle Output: http://jsfiddle.net/7h20gryw/

```css
    #f1_container {
      position: relative;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 450px;
      height: 281px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #f1_container {
      perspective: 1000;
    }
    #f1_card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: all 1.0s linear;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #f1_card {
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
      box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
    }
    .face {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .face.back {
      display: block;
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
       position: absolute;
       top: -9999px;
       left: -9999px;
       /* For mobile, it's typically better to position checkbox on top of clickable
          area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label {
      color: #ccc;
      font-style: italic;
    } 
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
      color: #f00;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="f1_container">
     <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
    <div id="f1_card" class="shadow flipme">
      <div class="front face">
    lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />
    lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />
    lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />lets see if anything happen <br />
      </div>
      <div class="back face center">
        <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
        <p>Any content can go here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<label for="ossm">Flip</label>
```